# Make field case insensitive in lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene, information-retrieval

How to make field case insensitive in lucene? Suppose, I have a following document:

User:xyz

Now, the document should be returned as a result for queries "user:xyz", "uSer:xyz", or "usEr:xyz".

The possible solution is to lowercasing the field while indexing and searching. But I need the exact value of the field when retrieving the document. Also, the other solution is to index the field twice, but that is also not the proper solution.

Here is the lucene example. When the query is "user:xyz" the document doesn't match. But if I use query "User:xyz" then the document matches because while indexing I have field as "User".

```
public void testFieldCaseSensitive() throws ParseException,
        QueryNodeException {
    StandardQueryParser parser = new StandardQueryParser();
    Query luceneQuery = parser.parse("user:xyz","");
    MemoryIndex memoryIndex = new MemoryIndex();
    memoryIndex.addField("User", "xyz", new StandardAnalyzer(
            Version.LUCENE_43));
    memoryIndex.search(luceneQuery);
    Assert.assertTrue(memoryIndex.search(luceneQuery) > 0);
}
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong it's already case insensitive I guess?

Comment: Can you provide some example? I have done with the values, but not the field itself.

Comment: Yeah sure, see my answer in a moment.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question correctly when I first read it.  Should have read more carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Field names are case sensitive.  As far as I know, there is no switch to flip in order to make them otherwise.

Probably the most reasonable way to approach this would be to ensure that, when indexing documents, all field names are lowercased.  Then, when querying, if you aren't querying against any case-sensitive field, you can just use `String.toLowercase()`, to make the entire query string lowercase as well, effectively making it case-insensitive.

Comment: I've done this myself, and it worked well -- the users really liked it.

Answer (score -1):

Apache Lucene is already case Insensitive what ever you search(Case sensitive or insensitive) it'll bring you results.

Basically the indexing you use already covers it and in most cases it's StandardAnalyzer. I've just tested it.

For Searching :

```
DocSearchEngine searcher = new DocSearchEngine();
ScoreDoc[] hits = searcher.searchIndexWithQueryParser("SeArch TeXT");
List<ResStructure> resultSet = searcher.printResultList(hits);
```

For Indexing :

```
writer = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir)),
    new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_45 ,new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_45)));
```

Comment: I have added lucene code in my post now. I am not referring to the value but the field. Could you please look at the code and comment?

Comment: I've looked into your code and I understand you're talking about value. Please add luceneQuery.setAllowLeadingWildcard( true ); It bypass the analyzer you choose and gives you result. see the link http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F

Comment: I tried parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true) but still it doesn't work.